# Linker /delayload is not fully working with winhttp.dll

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, portable-executable

I'm trying to prevent dll-hijacking vulnerability in my executable, which has only one explicit dynamic dependence - `winhttp.dll`.

My attempt is to use linker `/delayload:winhttp.dll` option and call `SetDefaultDllDirectories` in the very beginning of the program. Seems like it is working for some modules AND for `winhttp` itself, but not for it's dependencies - binary is still loading `mpr.dll` and a few other modules before `main` (and it is first trying to load it from my executable folder).

It is not helping to add `mpr.dll` to `/delayload` list - I'm getting `LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:mpr.dll ignored; no imports found from mpr.dll`.

Dependency Walker is showing me this dependence chain: `winhttp -> oleaut32 -> combase -> ole32 -> mpr`.

Why is this module loading before any of `winhttp` functions usage?

P.S. I really want to avoid using `LoadLibrary` + `GetProcAddress` manually.

Win 8.1, MSVS 2013 Update 5

Procmon:

[image: procmon log]

Dep. walker:

[image: dependency walker tree]

Comment: It would help if you included a small example program that uses winhttp just enough to reproduce the problem. Also, attach a debugger with loader snaps enabled for the process, instead of using the outdated Dependency Walker tool.

Comment: In Windows 10, I tried a delay-loaded `WinHttpOpen` call, which worked as expected. Loading winhttp loaded sechost, which in turn loaded rpcrt4. winhttp also depends on kernel32, kernelbase, and ucrtbase, but they were already loaded. All of these DLLs are protected by the KnownDlls list. The function call itself loaded other dependencies, including combase, but not oleaut32 or ole32 (which does have a delay-load dependency on mpr).

Comment: Realistically, you're better off just letting it load whatever it wants, then using `WinVerifyTrust` to check the signatures on the system dlls. Although that too isn't going to stop someone from using a debugger to patch out your checks.

Comment: delayload can not "partial working". it working on 100%. the `mpr.dll` loaded by some another reason. look under debugger why-who load it

Comment: @eryksun, the reason was - my executable name and AppCompat layer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @theB, my goal is to protect user, not my app. In case if malicious dll is located next to my executable - it will be able to do anything before `WinVerifyTrust` call.

Comment: If someone manages to place a DLL next to your application binary, they have far better ways to compromise the system than to attack your application. Unless you are installing to an unsecured location, it requires administrator privileges to write to the application directory.

Comment: @IInspectable, sure, but this executable usually can be runned w/o installation, just in the user Downloads folder for example.

Comment: This is a common problem with executable installers and portable apps. To run them securely, the user needs to move the executable to its own subdirectory, which few people would bother to do even if they were aware of the risk. Microsoft could address this with a manifest setting to remove the application directory from the loader's search path.

Comment: If you are trying to protect the user from *accidentally* loading (and executing) a rogue executable image, then checking for digital signatures is a viable option. You can combine that with implementing [delay load helper functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/understanding-the-helper-function) to get a first look at the module, before it's actually loaded.

Comment: Since VS2017 you can also specify the linker argument /DEPENDENTLOADFLAG:0x800 (assuming your dependencies are only system DLLs). See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230328-00/?p=107978

Answer (score 2):

It is crazy, but the true reason for this behaviour appears to be my executable name. It does contain a word "launcher", which seems to be the one, triggering Windows AppCompat layer.
The same executable renamed to "test1.exe" works all well.

Comment: @eryksun, my app manifest does contain `trustInfo` already with `requestedExecutionLevel` element. I also tried adding `compatibility` element with all 5 `supportedOS` guids, but `AcLayers.dll` is still loading (what results in `mpr` being loaded insecurely).